# filter data-value from array with jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, function, filter

This is my full code.

1. I want to store value in a array like mentioned: `dataArray = ["size", "color", "material"];`
2. Each "form-row" div contain data-value like "size", "color", "material" from the "dataArray"- array;
3. when I click on the "create order" button, In this case it will create a data-value called "color", becoz there is already two div contain "size", and "material" field; Each single click of the button create the structure once at a time;
4. I have also "delete" feature mentioned in "/*--remove div--*/" section;
5. But there is a issue to filter/find the right thing; There is a problem in "srch()" -function; plz help me out;

```js
//global variables
var dataArray = ["size", "color", "material"];
var dataArrayCreated = [];

var glb_array_len = dataArray.length;
var tot_len = $("#form-row_cst").find(".form-row").length;

/*--create_element--*/
function create_elment() {
  var html_structure = "<div class='form-row' data-value="+ dataArrayCreated[0] +"><div class='form-group col-md-3 col-sm-12'><label class='ad_prd_lbl'>Option name</label><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='"+ dataArrayCreated[0] +"' value='"+ dataArrayCreated[0] +"' id="+ dataArrayCreated[0]+'_val' +"></div><div class='form-group col-md-8 col-sm-12'><label class='ad_prd_lbl'>Option values</label><input type='text' id="+ dataArrayCreated[0]+'_inp' +" class='form-control' placeholder='Separate options with a comma'></div><div class='form-group col-md-1 col-sm-12'><button class='but_all btn_rmv' type='button'><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 20 20'><path d='M16 6a1 1 0 1 1 0 2h-1v9a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H6a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V8H4a1 1 0 1 1 0-2h12zM9 4a1 1 0 1 1 0-2h2a1 1 0 1 1 0 2H9zm2 12h2V8h-2v8zm-4 0h2V8H7v8z'></path></svg></button></div></div>";

  $("#form-row_cst").append(html_structure).appendTo("#form-row_cst");
}

//search function
function srch() {
  $.each(dataArray, function (index, value) {
    console.log(value);
    $("#form-row_cst").find(".form-row").each(function () {
      console.log($(this).attr('data-value'));
      if( $(this).attr('data-value') !== value ) {
        dataArrayCreated[0] = value;
        console.log("found - "+dataArrayCreated[0]);
      }
    });
  });
}

//main function
function main_fn() {
 if( tot_len <= glb_array_len ) {
   //console.log("count Data - "+ tot_len+"-items");
   srch();
   create_elment();
 }
 else {
   console.log("Invalid Data - "+ tot_len+"-items");
 }
}

/*---click btn to create structure--*/
$("#clone_btn").click(function(){
  //find created element from list
  main_fn();

  if( ($("#form-row_cst").find(".form-row").length) > (dataArray.length)-1 ) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});

/*--remove div--*/
$(document).on("click","#form-row_cst .btn_rmv", function(){
  //check if this div is last child of "#form-row_cst"
  if( $("#form-row_cst").find(".form-row").length-1 < 1) {
    alert("sorry, you can't delete this items");
  }
  else {
    //remove div
    $(this).parents(".form-row").remove();
  }
  if( ($("#form-row_cst").find(".form-row").length) < (dataArray.length)+1 ) {
    $("#clone_btn").show();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  color: rgba(70, 90, 110, 0.85);
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: #f3f6f9;
}

.box {
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.order_details {
  padding: 15px;
}

.dropdown_div {
  display: none;
}

.gry_of_bg {
  background-color: #f9fafb;
}

.form-row>.col, .form-row>[class*=col-] {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.form-result_outer {
  padding: 15px 0px 0px;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

.ad_prd_lbl {
  font-size: .8rem;
  color: #212b35;
  margin-bottom: .25rem;
}

#form-row_cst .form-row .form-control,
#form-row_cst .but_all {
  min-height: 36px;
}

.input_tags_cnt {
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
}

#form-row_cst .input_tags_cnt .bootstrap-tagsinput {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: rgba(120, 130, 140, 0.2);
  min-height: auto;
}

.bootstrap-tagsinput {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  color: #555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-width: 100%;
  line-height: 22px;
  cursor: text;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.bootstrap-tagsinput input {
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0 6px;
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  max-width: inherit;
}

#form-row_cst .form-row input,
#form-row_cst .form-row .bootstrap-tagsinput input {
  color: #222;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}
.input_tags_cnt .bootstrap-tagsinput>input {
  width: 100%;
}

.but_all {
  padding: 5px 12px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #c4cdd5;
  line-height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  min-height: 34px;
}
#form-row_cst .but_all {
  margin-top: 24px;
}
#form-row_cst .form-row .form-control,
#form-row_cst .but_all {
  min-height: 36px;
}
#form-row_cst .form-row .form-control {
  width: 100%;
}

.but_all svg {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.cbd_table_product_table {
  border: 0px;
  min-width: 650px;
}

.cbd_table_product_table > thead > tr > th,
.cbd_table_product_table > tbody > tr > td {
  border-left: 0px;
  border-right: 0px;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebeef0;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 0.86rem;
}

.cbd_table_product_table > thead > tr > th {
  padding: .5rem .4rem;
  color: #212b35;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.cbd_table_product_table > thead > tr > th:first-child,
.cbd_table_product_table > tbody > tr > td:first-child {
  padding-left: 3px;
}

.custom-checkbox {
  margin: 0rem;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0px;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.custom-checkbox .custom-control-input {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}
.custom-control-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: .25rem;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: #ddd;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
}
.custom-checkbox .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-indicator {
  background-color: #17a2b8;
}
.custom-checkbox .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-indicator {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' v…M6.564.75l-3.59 3.612-1.538-1.55L0 4.26 2.974 7.25 8 2.193z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E);
}

.tb_Variant_tag {
  font-size: .8rem;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  line-height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.color_tb_Variant {
  color: #29bc94;
}
.size_tb_Variant {
  color: #ff9517;
}
.meterial_tb_Variant {
  color: #763eaf;
}
.tb_Variant_tag:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #637381;
  height: 4px;
  width: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 4px;
  font-size: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="box">
      <div class="order_details">
        <header class="prd_hdr clearfix">
          <h6>Variants</h6>
        </header>
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>Add variants if this product comes in multiple versions, like different sizes or colors.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix dropdown_div" style="display: block;">
          <div class="order_details gry_of_bg">
              <div class="clearfix" id="form-row_cst">
                  <div class="form-row" data-value="size">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                          <label class="ad_prd_lbl">Option name</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="size_val" placeholder="Size" value="size">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                          <label class="ad_prd_lbl">Option values</label>
                          <input type="text" id="size_inp" class="form-control" placeholder="Separate options with a comma">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-1 col-sm-12">
                          <button class="but_all btn_rmv" type="button">
                              <svg id="delete-minor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                  <path d="M16 6a1 1 0 1 1 0 2h-1v9a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H6a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V8H4a1 1 0 1 1 0-2h12zM9 4a1 1 0 1 1 0-2h2a1 1 0 1 1 0 2H9zm2 12h2V8h-2v8zm-4 0h2V8H7v8z"></path>
                              </svg>
                          </button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-row" data-value="material">
                      <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-12">
                          <label class="ad_prd_lbl">Option name</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="material_val" placeholder="material" value="material">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-sm-12">
                          <label class="ad_prd_lbl">Option values</label>
                          <input type="text" id="material_inp" class="form-control" placeholder="Separate options with a comma">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group col-md-1 col-sm-12">
                          <button class="but_all btn_rmv" type="button">
                              <svg id="delete-minor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                  <path d="M16 6a1 1 0 1 1 0 2h-1v9a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H6a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V8H4a1 1 0 1 1 0-2h12zM9 4a1 1 0 1 1 0-2h2a1 1 0 1 1 0 2H9zm2 12h2V8h-2v8zm-4 0h2V8H7v8z"></path>
                              </svg>
                          </button>
                      </div>
                  </div>

              </div>
              <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                      <button class="but_all" type="button" id="clone_btn">Create order</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It appears that you want `srch()` to find every item in `dataArray` for which there is currently no corresponding form-row. And you want `main_fn()` to call `srch()`then create any missing rows. Is that correct?

Comment: yes...there is no "display: none" type things. row will append with button click function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find this kind of thing (and programming in general) simpler and more satisfying once you know how to exploit functions' ability to accept arguments and return values.

On the basis that you want :

- `srch()` to find every item in `dataArray` for which there is currently no corresponding form-row.
- `main_fn()` to call `srch()` then create any missing rows.

First write `srch()` to return a filtered copy of `dataArray`, as follows :

```
function srch() {
    // Return a filtered copy of `dataArray` leaving items for which there is currently no corresponding form-row.
    return dataArray.filter(function(item) {
        return $("#form-row_cst .form-row").filter(function() {
            return $(this).data('value') === item;
        }).length === 0;
    });
}
```

Then write `main_fn()` to loop through the array returned by `srch()` calling `create_elment()`, as follows :

```
function main_fn() {
    if( tot_len <= glb_array_len ) {
        console.log("count Data - " + tot_len + "-items");
        srch().forEach(create_elment);
    } else {
        console.log("Invalid Data - " + tot_len + "-items");
    }
}
```

For this to work, `create_elment()` needs to accept an argument, as follows :

```
function create_elment(item) {
    $("<div class='form-row' data-value=" + item + "><div class='form-group col-md-3 col-sm-12'><label class='ad_prd_lbl'>Option name</label><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='" + item + "' value='" + item + "' id=" + item + '_val' + "></div><div class='form-group col-md-8 col-sm-12'><label class='ad_prd_lbl'>Option values</label><input type='text' id=" + item + '_inp' +" class='form-control' placeholder='Separate options with a comma'></div><div class='form-group col-md-1 col-sm-12'><button class='but_all btn_rmv' type='button'><svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 20 20'><path d='M16 6a1 1 0 1 1 0 2h-1v9a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H6a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V8H4a1 1 0 1 1 0-2h12zM9 4a1 1 0 1 1 0-2h2a1 1 0 1 1 0 2H9zm2 12h2V8h-2v8zm-4 0h2V8H7v8z'></path></svg></button></div></div>").appendTo("#form-row_cst");
}
```

The outer var `dataArrayCreated` can be dispensed with.

**EDIT**

To add just one row per click of `#clone_btn`, you can leave `srch()` as it is (my version) and in `main_fn()` change the line ...

```
srch().forEach(create_elment);
```

to ...

```
srch().slice(0, 1).forEach(create_elment);
```

That way, `srch()` still returns an array of items representing all missing rows, and `main_fn()` is in control of which of them it will operate on.

If `srch()` returns empty array, then `srch().slice(0, 1)` will also be empty array and `create_elment` will not be called. Unless you particularly want to see those messages in the log, the `if(tot_len <= glb_array_len)` test is probably no longer necessary?

Comment: Thank you...
but i also mentioned each row will create in each click of the button. 
Suppose I have just one row. Then I click "create order" button, it will create two rows. but I need one row at a time.
overall functionally is great;

Comment: Ah, so you want to create a "size" row,  "material" row, then a "colour" row , in that order, one row at a time? If so, your original code was closer than I thought.

Comment: partially correct...I don't want to add "size" row, "material" row, then a "colour" row  in that order. But yes, **I want to add any of this missing row** one at a time.

Comment: See my suggested edit above. I think it will do what you want.